# Publish update-only distribution to Apple App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

If I have an app that preloads a database when it first launches, **is there a way to then in future publish an update only version for the app?**

(IE excluding the preloaded db file so the update isn't bigger than necessary as an existing user wont ever overwrite their preloaded db - but at the same time being able to publish one WITH the preloaded db so that new downloaders will get a newer version of the db)

If there's an alternative way to approach it please let me know. Just to clarify, the app automatically updates the db with data when used - that's why I have no need to include the preload for every app distribution for users who have already downloaded.

I've looked on Google and can't find an answer - but maybe I'm just not using the right terms!

Comment: This might be helpful to see what's possible: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1779/_index.html I don't think it's possible to achive what you want though.

Comment: "the update package contains instructions on how to transform the prior version of the app into the new version of the app" - could this be what I'm looking for?

Comment: Those instructions are automatically generated by the app store by comparing your new and old app bundles. You can not directly provide those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an update to your application, your app will need to check if the user already have a database in the Document folder.  If one doesn't exists, your updated app will copy the default database from the Application Bundle.

Also, if you add features to the app, new table or columns to your existing database schema it would be nice to use [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html).

Excerpt from Apple Docs - [Reducing Download Size for iOS App Updates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1779/_index.html):

- Starting with iOS 6, the app store will **automatically** produce an update package for all new versions of apps submitted to the store.

Comment: Thanks, got that but what I was really trying to get at is the actual download rather than the database itself. The same thing could apply for any type of file - I want the user not to have to redownload a 30mb file they may already have.

This being said I did also read your last point from the docs about automatic update package generating but didn't quite understand from the docs whether that would cover my basis.

Comment: Basically you just package your update application and submit to AppStore.  When a user goes to update their installed app on their device, the AppStore will only send them the new/changed files.  Thus reducing the size of the download package.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. So I guess my original question is going to be a no as an answer then (in my case) as my database package will technically be different when I publish an update, so it will be included in the generated update package. Doh... this isn't good.